# ListView IsRefreshing & IsPullToRefreshEnabled is not found in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

We are not able to find the below events in `Xamarin.Forms ListView Control`.

```
Error: 
'xamarin.forms.ListView' does not contain definition for '**IsRefreshing**'

'xamarin.forms.ListView' does not contain definition for '**IsPullToRefreshEnabled**'
```

Note: We are using the `Xamarin Latest Version` `(Xamarin 4.0.0.1717)`.

Kindly Suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to Xamarin.Forms Dll is not updated to latest version from Visual Studio (I have updated only from Visual studio and shows up-to date).

By Opening the same source in Xamarin Studio and updating the Xamarin Forms Dll, the above properties are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see that you're using `Xamarin.Forms 1.3` when you click the **properties** of `Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll` from project references.

For upgrading it(in VS) right click the solution and click **Manage Nuget Packages**. Then update `Xamarin.Forms` `dll`'s.